# Can't debug c++ project because unable to static library start program *.lib

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, static-libraries

I'm using a library (Astro.lib) which i've built without problems (i guess this is a release build).

I've also built a project which references the library (it runs as a release exe fine) but i can't debug the project because i get the message 'unable to start program 'Astro.lib'.

If i try to debug the lib then i get the same error, so I guess its something to do with not building for debug my lib but not sure how to modify.

I've tried changing the properties pages using MSDN info but not sure i'm addressing the correct problem. What changes should i make to the properties pages of the library of linking project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with a debug-build of that lib. Your problem is the fact that the debugger assumes that it should execute that library instead of your application. A release-build would not prevent you from debugging (especially on MSVC) - it would just result into some weird behaviours of the debugger once you single-step into functions covered by that lib.

Comment: Ahh ok. Long time since i did some coding. I thought F5 would debug the selected project in the solution explorer

Comment: Seems there's no problem at all. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've also built a project which references the library

*That's* the project you want to debug.  You probably just have the wrong project selected as the startup project of your solution.  It is marked in **bold** type in the Solution Explorer window.

Right-click the project that uses the library and select "Set as StartUp Project"

Answer (score 0):

your debug settings are wrong - you're trying to debug the lib, not the exe.

Chances are you've set the library project as the one that is started by the debugger (eg the "startup project" that shows in bold in Visual studio). Change your solution explorer so the main executable project is bold and try again, or right click on it and selecty the appropriate "run in the debugger" option.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:
Make sure you have the Solution Explorer view (VIEW->SOLUTION EXPLORER). 
Then, right click on SOLUTION  at the top, and click EXPLORER.

Under COMMON PROPERTIES->STARTUP PROJECT -> SINGLE STARTUP PROJECT, choose the project that you want VS to execute. Note that this project has the property CONFIGURATION TYPE set as APPLICATION(.EXE). This can b found under the project's properties->CONFIGURATION PROPERTIES->GENERAL.

Hope that helps.